# Referral program in Metaplex storefront

Tags: solana, metaplex

What is the best way to create "Referral program" in Metaplex storefront?

A referral program works by inviting customers to become brand ambassadors. They join the referral marketing program and get a unique code or link to share with their network. so the referral program tracks the activity of a customers’ code or link. If someone purchases using it, the referrer will earn a reward.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you'll have to implement this yourself in a traditional web2 way with a database and backend with a login system.

When a user makes a purchase via web3 you could modify the purchase function to then also store a referer in your database upon purchase confirmation.

Then when a user logs in you could then refer to the database to see how many referals the user has generated for you and show them on a form of dashboard for them to see.

Unfortuantely do the to broad question in general I can't really give you much more of an elaborate answer than that currently.